# How to check earthing using handheld digital multimeter?

Tags: multimeter

I would like to know to how to check for earthing (electrical) ina house using handheld DMM.

Comment: You can buy plug in devices for next to nothing which will tell you via indicators of any fault (e.g. L-N reversed, missing E, etc.).

Comment: @TomCarpenter -- most faults, but not all -- a reverse polarity bootleg ground won't get caught by a 3-light tester

Answer (score 3):

The simple, but somewhat unreliable method uses a long wire and a DMM. Connect one end of the wire to a known, good earth contact (maybe next to the location where your fuse box is installed). Measure the resistance from the other end of the wire to the ground connector of the outlet/device to be tested. If you read a small resistance, you are probably good: Your multimeter tests the connection from your device's ground connection through the house installation to the central ground and your long test wire. However, there is a gotcha: Maybe somewhere along the installation, there is a bad contact that will fuse even with a small (say less than 1 A) current. Once it fuses, you end up with a dangerous situation, because your real fuse will not have blown at just 1 A and still supply current to the system. Your DMM will use just some micro- or milliamps and hence will not be able to "blow" the unintentional fuse (read: bad connection).

The solution to this problem would be a current source (strong bench supply, professional tester - but the latter es expensive) limited to whatever maximum current your installation and fuses are rated at (16 A, 20 A, maybe even 30 A?). Feed the current through the PE connection from the wall outlet to the central ground connection of your house and measure the voltage drop using the voltage range of your DMM. You're good when the voltage drop or the resistance (voltage divided by current) is small. Local regulations will tell you how small is small enough. To get an idea, you might try to calculate what resistance you expect using the cross-section and length of the wiring you have used in your installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Brief Answer** 
Yes, you can! (This is not a proper way, but you can measure the earthing )

You can measure the earthing by measuring the potential between line, neutral and earth point.

- Theoretically voltage difference between neutral and earth will be
  zero, but practically it will be 2 to 4 AC volts. If you get closer
  than zero voltage you are having proper earthing.

  And also measure the voltage between phase and Earth. It should give
  the more or less same value which is measured between phase and
  neutral.

You can do that by changing the digital multimeter mode to AC voltage and then measure the voltgae between neutral and earth

Comment: I'd at least measure voltage between phase, neutral and earth. And in general, a DMM is not the right device, since good earthing also is a matter of resistance. If earthing has a resistance of 1000Ohm, your voltages would be fine, while earthing obviously is not.

Comment: His question is "in a house using handheld DMM." i haved added answer for his question. 

He might not have highly precision Megger in home to measure the earth resistance ! 
Anyway i have made some edits. which will clear the answer. 
Thanks for ur comment @sweber

Answer (score 0):

You need an AC voltmeter and either a clamp-meter (recommended) or an AC amperemeter.

Set-up a circuit whereby a current is passed through the earthing connection. The current should be relevant to the installation being tested, something like 15-20A for residential earthing. For example, a bunch of electric heaters. Measure this current with the clamp-meter or amperemeter.

At the same time, insert a test rod some distance from the earthing area. Something like 5 meters away should be enough.

While the known large current is still flowing, measure the AC voltage difference between the earthing connection being tested and the test rod.

You obtain a voltage to the ground, then derive the earthing resistance as R=U/I.

The refined methods used by electrical engineers will move the test rod to various distances and compensate for the distributed resistance of the soil, that create some residual voltage on the testing rod compared to "true ground". For a typical 1-5 Ohm residential earthing resistance, the effect is completely negligible.